# What is the difference between an executable and a shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04

The properties of `ls`  show it is an  `executable`.

[image]

And properties of  `kmod`  show it is a  `shared library`.

[image]

Im trying to check for `executables` and hash them in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Is there any way to differentiate `executables` from the other types? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is little sense in hashing executable programs and not shared libraries.

Comment: i wanted to start with just executables and later for other types but i dont know how to differentiate between them in a program.

Comment: This is about the same as offering checksums for files with names that start with letters A to O but not P to Z. Completely arbitrary and unnecessary.

Comment: oh okay, now it makes more sense to provide checksums for both executables and shared libraries.Thankyou!

Comment: Both types contain executable code and may execute malicious code if malware is present, so it's good to checksum both.

Answer (score 2):

Executable is a Load file which executes directly in system as a program. As per your question, "ls" is a executable which is used to 
list the current directory contents. The load for "ls" is placed in "/bin" or you can check using command "which ls". Shared library are the one which do some task that is commonly accessed or used by many executables. These library are loaded into the memory only once and accessed by many programs(executables) at runtime.